# Flutter How to not show the [] Brackets of a list when being displayed as a text?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to display a list rendered in text. But when I do I see the []

I have tried the following.

```
Text(hashList.toString().replaceAll("(^\\[|\\])", ""))
```

Brackets are still there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
Text(hashList.join())
```

or you can use a delimiter

```
Text(hashList.join(','))
```